# Was Alexis Clairaut the first to discover Clairaut's theorem for the variation of gravity on spheroids?

Tags: biographical-details

My question refers to the problem of the figure of the earth, and is intended to establish if Isaac Newton was or was not the first to discover the equation for the variation of gravity with latitude on an oblate spheroid.  As far as I know, Newton calculated a value of  $\frac54m$ for the eccentricity of earth, where $m$ is the equatorial ratio of centrifugal to gravitational force, and calculated $f = \frac{1}{230}$ for the ellipticity of earth. Later in book 3 of Principia, Newton stated that the gravitational force varies as the square of the sine of latitude, a statement that agrees in form with Clairaut's formula. My only question is whether Newton and Clairaut formulae are identical up to constants in the equation?

An answer to this question will help me clarify the historical context surrounding the problem of the figure of the earth, so I'll be glad to get an answer.

Comment: Newton assumed fluid Earth of equal density in his calculation, so his $f$ was off. In 1743 Clairaut did a more general calculation where the density was assumed constant along ellipsoidal layers, the resulting formula is of the "same" form. But then you can get this form (without identification of the constants) just by sticking the polar equation of an ellipse into the inverse square law, that's not saying much. See http://www.historicalgeophysics.ax/sp/26.pdf and http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath182/kmath182.htm for what the actual controversies were about.

Comment: Hello conifold!! I have to clarify a certain misunderstanding that i have about the "squared sine" rule. Does the squared sine rule take into account the fictitous centrifugal force of not? Because if it does, i do understand the squared sine rule. But if this rules speaks about the net gravitational force by a spheroid, then i don't understand the origin of this rule. So what's the answer to my question?

Comment: It does, but that goes for both Newton and Clairaut. The main difference between them is that Clairaut's model of fluid Earth was more sophisticated, and so he could account for the divergence of the measurements of $f$ from Newton's predictions by speculating that the density of Earth changes from the core to the surface. But you'll get the same "rule" (up to constants) even if you simply ignore the centrifugal "force" (no rotation) but assume the ellipsoidal shape.